# Why does C allow conversions between incompatible pointer types?

Tags: c99

I'm wondering why C99 allows conversions between incompatible pointer types:

```
void f(int* p)
{
}

void c(char* p)
{
   f(p);
}
```

Does C11 also allow them? Are conforming implementations required to diagnose such conversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C99 doesn't permit implicit conversion between pointers of different types (except to/from `void*`).  here's what the C99 Rationale says:

> It is invalid to convert a pointer to an object of any type to a pointer to an object of a different type without an explicit cast.

This is a consequence of the rules for assignment, which has a constraint that one of the following shall hold (when pointers are involved) (C99 6.5.16.1 "Simple assignment"):

> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the
>     qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object or incomplete type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of void, and
>     the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type
>     pointed to by the right;
> - the left operand is a pointer and the right is a null pointer constant

Passing a pointer as an argument to a prototyped function follows the same rules because (C99 6.5.2.2/7 "Function calls"):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
>   if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters

Both C90 and C11 have similar wording.

I believe that many compilers (including GCC) relax this constraint to issue only a warning because there's too much legacy code that depends on it.  Keep in mind that `void*` was an invention of the ANSI C standard, so pre-standard, and probably a lot of post-standard, code generally used `char*` or `int*` as a 'generic' pointer type.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "incompatible" pointer types.

The beauty of C is that it allows the programmer to do what they want. It is up to the programmer to decide what is compatible vs. incompatible. Other languages that claim to force "`class`" or "`type`" cohesion do so in a limited way. The moment that the objects are allowed to be referenced a pointer is used and a class mismanagement can kick in.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is plenty of incompatible pointer types, C actually has a much stricter typing system for pointers than it does for regular variables. This is mainly regulated through the rules in C11 6.3.2.3 regarding pointer conversion, but also through the rules for assignment as quoted in another answer.